TV Series about trolls that are guided by a talking cube
It aired on Australian TV's ABC Chanel in the 1990's as i remember i was in primary school at the time i saw it.
there are these little people who i think are trolls (as a child to me kinda looked like the Trollies), they are forced out of their home because of a fire and are left homeless, one of them has this black cube which glows when it talks and seems to be guiding them.
there is a scene where they are traveling and they've stolen a car, they've rigged it with ropes so they can drive it and i think it get's pulled over by a cop and he tries to see who's driving it but finds no one.
The group arrive at this other place inhabited by other small people who i think are the same as them (being trolls) which is either a mill itself or under a mill as i remember that when they arrive the group frantically starts eating, one shot has one of them opening a grain bag and eating it.
In the credits it's just the Black Cube but the view is panning around it.

I think you mean Truckers from 1992, a stop-motion series based on Terry Pratchett's book about creatures called Nomes:

It starts when a cop stops a truck and finds that it's driverless; it's actually driven by them. And the cube is a computer called The Thing. You can see that scene with the cop (as well as the cube) in this video:



And here are the end credits, where you can see the talking black cube again.
